# Lost firefox tabs due to crash

Tags: 14.04, firefox, plugins, session, history

I use the *Save Session* version 1.3.1.6.1 plugin in firefox to save my current sessions. I had kept 3 windows full of tabs for all almost a year when yesterday my firefox crashed. Now I can't find any of my tabs.

Since I unknowingly started firefox, I know that the firefox's own saved session is gone.

**Is there anyway I can recover my tabs from the *Saved Session* plugin?**

P.S: I use Firefox version 35.0.1 in Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to recover them from browsing history.

Found in Firefox 'profiles' location (this is from Mozilla website, Firefox for Windows but may help in finding the location)

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data

> The ***places.sqlite*** file contains all your Firefox bookmarks and lists of all the files you've downloaded and websites you’ve visited. The bookmarkbackups folder stores bookmark backup files, which can be used to restore your bookmarks

I can't actually check mine atm, doing 4th Linux re-install in 2 days :/